# Akka Actor: Path lookup efficiency

Tags: akka

I am creating actors that represents physical devices and their state. As devices come online I create them "on demand" by sending and Identify message to the actor's path and then if it does not exist yet I create one. Potentially, there could be several million of these devices.

My concern is that the Identify look-up will take a performance hit as the number of actors increases. Is this a valid concern?

I was considering using a router strategy to segment the actors, but then I found that searching on the path with a wild card for the router yielded ActorIdentities from each router. I assume that a ConsistentHashingRouter would suit this scenario, but before I go down that rabbit hole I just want to make sure I am not optimizing prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

The entity which creates an actor is only its parent (there no other way), which means that that parent actor does not need to use `Identify` at all, just check `context.child(name).isDefined`. That is very efficient, although you might want to shard your devices across multiple parents if you really have a massive number of them.